Content security policy used in frames
after a pentest they discover that i need to add the sandbox directive to content security policy.
I have a page with 4 frame
<frameset rows="35,*,20" framespacing="0" border="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame name="testata" scrolling="no" noresize src="top.asp" id="testata">
    <frameset cols="260,*" id="framesetCentrale">
        <frame name="funzioni" src="menu.asp" scrolling="auto" class="bordofrmdestra" id="funzioni">
        <frame name="visualizza" src="visualizza.asp" scrolling="auto" id="visualizza">
    </frameset>
        <frame name="fondo" scrolling="no" noresize src="fondo.asp" id="fondo">
        <noframes>
        <body>

        <p>La pagina corrente utilizza i frame. Questa caratteristica non è
        supportata dal browser in uso. Aggiornate il vostro browser.</p>

        </body>
        </noframes>
</frameset>


If i add this directive i cannot click on a td on frame visualizza to refresh the frame funzioni, visualizza (itself) and fondo.
The script to do that is on page in frame visualizza:
$(document).on('click','#tabellaArchivi td', function() {
        archivio = $(this).attr("id");
        
        //parent.funzioni.location='menu.asp?sceltaarch=1&arc='+ archivio;
        window.top.funzioni.location='menu.asp?sceltaarch=1&arc='+ archivio;
        window.top.visualizza.location='visualizza.asp?arc='+ archivio;
        window.top.fondo.location='fondo.asp?paginafunzioni=menu.asp?sceltaarch=1$arc='+ archivio +'&paginavisualizza=visualizza.asp?arc='+ archivio;
    });

tried both method (parent.funzioni or window.top.funzioni) to refresh frame and not work.
When i click on the td i receive
visualizza.asp:26  Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'http://localhost/login/menu.asp' from frame with URL 'http://localhost/login/visualizza.asp'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

(anonimo) @ visualizza.asp:26
dispatch @ jquery.js:2
v.handle @ jquery.js:2
visualizza.asp:26  Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'href' property on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'menu.asp?sceltaarch=1&arc=2-SILF Finanziamenti'.
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (visualizza.asp:26:31)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js:2:40035)
    at v.handle (jquery.js:2:38006)

My actual CSP, for all the frame is:
frame-ancestors 'self'; default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'report-sample' 'nonce-****'; style-src 'self' 'report-sample' 'nonce-****'; object-src 'none'; frame-src 'self'; child-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; manifest-src 'none'; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self'; media-src 'self'; worker-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; report-uri https://xxx.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly; report-to https://xxx.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/reportOnly; sandbox allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox;

i tried to add all the value for sandbox whitout success, tried to use window.top.framename instead of parent.framename in the javascript code
I expect that i can refresh a frame from another. There is a solution to my problem? thanks in advance

CSP prevents the frame from being correctly loaded by the main page. So you will need to edit the CSP of the main page by adding the domain of the iframe to the frame-src section of the CSP of the main page. Instead, you were trying to edit the CSP of the iframe.
Besides this, you will need to edit the CORS headers of your iframe page too, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS, notably the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Thank you for response, i have added, as you suggested, on the parent page frame-src 'self' http://localhost/; child-src 'self' http://localhost/; in CSP and on both iframe (funzioni and visualizza) the header access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost/, still not working and CSP block my script. CORS directive work on localhost? need to test on real server? i try to post an example somewhere so you can give a look
EDIT - i forgot to say that all iframe have the same site origin

@abellos thank you, let me know when you have the test env ready

I prepared this link https://www.siaarchivi.com/help_csp/sceltadb.asp?cspon=1 if u set cspon to 0 the CSP sandbox is not active (is the behavior I would like also with CSP), if you set 1 CSP is activated.
Try to click on the LOGO image to get the error in console, you can also click on the second combobox on the frame funzioni, to return to the home page click at the bottom the link "Selez. Archivio".
For now i added the sandbox CSP only on page visualizza.asp and menu.asp, when it work i extend to all the frames.
Thanks for your help.

@abellos when selecting an option using the second dropdown I get the error of Uncaught DOMException: The operation is insecure. If this is the issue you see, then it was also reported to BugZilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1742396

yes is it the case, if you try with edge or chrome say that i not have the permission to access the other frame cause of the sandbox. EDIT so there is no solution?

@abellos this seems to be a further issue. So what I described in the answer is needed indeed, but this also needs to be resolved. I am not aware of a solution for this next issue at this point, unfortunately.
